# adding suffix in javascript option value?

Tags: javascript

I want to add suffix **Yrs.** in options list which are coming through javascript code is as below:

```
var opt = $('<option value=0>--select--</option>');
$('#period').append(opt);
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = result[i]['product_period'];
    option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" " + result[i]['product_period']));
    df.appendChild(option)

}

elm.appendChild(df);
```

how can it be done. i know its something simple. pls help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" " + result[i]['product_period']+' Yrs'));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
option.value = result[i]['product_period']+'Yrs';
option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" " + result[i]['product_period']+'Yrs'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do at each iteration

```
option.label = " " + result[i]['product_period'] + " Yrs";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" " + result[i]['product_period'] + " Yrs"));
```